# Combine two multiline textboxes in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, textbox, multiline

I need to combine two multiline textboxes in vb net, like this:

```
textbox1:
a
b
c
d

textbox2:
1
2
3
4

textbox3:
a1
b2
c3
d4
```

Just a form with three textboxes. And a button to merge/combine/concatenate each value from t1 and t2, in t3.

one of my attempts:

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

```
    For Each line In TextBox1.Lines
        For Each linex In TextBox2.Lines
            Me.TextBox3.Text += line & linex
            Me.TextBox3.Text += Environment.NewLine
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

but result combination of lines (lines=linex) taken by two  (a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3...)

Comment: So, write some code. What have you tried?

Comment: @user 2284877 This should set you on your way  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.text.aspx

Answer (score 1):

this may be one of the way to do this.
1 -Split the text of textbox 1 and 2 .
2- you will get array for each textbox of equal count (in mentioned case).
3 - using for loop, make the text of third textbox as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Does VB.net not allow you to go:

```
Dim example as string = textBox1.Text & " " & textBox2.Text & " " & textBox3.Text
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Dim example as string = textBox1.Text & char(10) & textBox2.Text & char(10)  & textBox3.Text can we not do this

Comment: please add formatting to your answer so it's easier for others to read and understand your solution.